# How to exclude codes under `if __name__ == '__main__':` from SonarQube test coverage

Tags: python, sonarqube

I have some requirement that at least 80% of the line coverage need to be achieved. I have some file where a large portion of the code is under `if __name__ == '__main__':` which need not to be tested.

How can I instruct SonarQube to exclude that portion of code from test coverage. I have seen there are options to exclude files and module using `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.coverage.exclusions`. It would be a great help for me to exclude some parts of a file. For example, I want to exclude everything in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block below from sonarQube:

```
#Test Everything inside this method
def do_something():
  # Some code

# Do not test and include the following codes in the SonarQube coverage
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # A lot of codes for running different functions of this module
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found solution to the problem. That's why I am adding for other to be helped. We have used `pytest` and `coverage` to compute the coverage report. SonarQube just read that coverage report.
To exclude some line we have add the following inline comment after that line:

```
# pragma: no cover
```

For example the line `print("Hello World")` will be excluded from the test coverage report,

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Hello World") # pragma: no cover
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to first explore the options offered by the code coverage tool you are using.
As for Sonar, most language analyzers exclude the line of code that has `//NOSONAR` at the end of it. This works for rule violations for sure. You may try out if it works for code coverage as well. Even if it works you will have to put it on every line of code under `if __name__ == '__main__':`.
For the documentation on this, you may refer to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/#header-1

This is the best what I could think of ..:)

Comment: Did you mean `# NOSONAR` for Python?

Comment: I haven't used Python analyzer but the documentation says, "Most language analyzers support the use of the generic mechanism: //NOSONAR". So, one could try it with Python and see if it works.

Comment: it does not seem to have any impact on code coverage. However, the sonarlint rules are disabled for the lines after adding `# NOSONAR` . Is there any trick to instruct that those lines will not be used in code coverage as well.

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam which tool are you using for the code coverage? Will need to see its documentation if it supports skipping certain code segments within a file.

Comment: we run pytest with coverage in jenkins and that creates a coverage report